# Adding Claims to a SAML token usign Azure AD Single SingOn

Tags: azure

We have an application that uses multiple IDP for authentication. We receive a SAML token with some extra claims where we authenticate on. We also want to use Azure AD as a trusted IDP, but how can our customer add the required claims to their returned SAML token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no option to add claims to the Azure AD generated SAML token. To do this you have to add your application to the Azure AD Application Gallery. For Azure AD premium user this can be done for your own applications that accept SAM.

For non Azure AD premium user you have to add your application to the Azure AD Gallery, see https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-app-gallery-listing/.